# Two DNS service providers

Tags: domain, cloudflare, domain-name-system

Is there a way to have two DNS service providers?

I have DNS Made Easy account and Cloudflare but I want to use both.

My domain registrar has nameservers pointing to DNS Made Easy

How would this work?

Comment: Why do you want to?

Comment: So I can benefit from both services obviously use Cloudflare for CDN and Performance Optimization and DNS Made Easy for any other DNS management

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, it'd be possible - you'd specify both provider's DNS servers for the domain, and you'd need to make sure the same sets of records are on both providers. That said, I've never seen this done - there's generally not much point.

In CloudFlare's case, though, this isn't possible, because part of CloudFlare's magic (and the reason they need to be your DNS provider for a domain) is that they frequently change your domain's IPs to point to their caching servers. You'd wind up with disparate sets of records in your two DNS providers, and as a result some users would get the wrong data.

https://support.cloudflare.com/entries/22451048-how-do-i-use-cloudfare-without-changing-my-dns

CloudFlare's DNS should be capable of everything DNS Made Easy can handle, so I'd recommend just using CloudFlare's offering if you're looking to use their systems.

Answer (score 1):

YES you can do it, although I'd use an alternative....You can have more than one authortative server.  First choose a master file and then get everything the way you want it, being sure to name the other DNS servers you want to be authoritative in forward zone NS records.  Set the other DNS servers to be slaves and get the data from your single master.   Thus updating is only done one place but the authoritative servers are at other locations as well as the master.

You establish your authoritative servers under your domain registration or they will not be contacted.  I think that you might even be able to specify the slave servers here and keep your master DNS server out of the advertised mix (except for the required NS records).

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to have two DNS service providers?

Presuming you are talking about authoritative service (i.e. a service provider serving your zone data, and not about providing answers to your clients' recursive queries) it's actually not that uncommon for organizations with high availability needs to contract with a secondary DNS provider.

You should only have one master server, but secondaries can slave from that, receiving data by zone transfer.

That said, if you require a provider with a simple web management interface, you may find that many assume that you are using their servers for all of your DNS needs, and thus they may not have interface options available for controlling the relationship between their servers and DNS nameservers you are also using at another provider.